# XSLT Regrouping based on attribute value ID

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have following XML

```
<group id="a">
<Name>Number One</Name>
<setgroup>
<refgroup ID="b">
<refgroup ID="c">
</setgroup>
</group>


<group id="b">
<Name>Number Two</Name>
<setgroup>
<refgroup ID="c">
<refgroup ID="e">
</setgroup>
</group>

<group id="c">
<Name>Number Three</Name>
<setgroup>
<refgroup ID="g">
<refgroup ID="f">
</setgroup>
</group>
```

As an output I need to have

```
<Product>
   <Name>Number One</Name>
   <Product>
    <Name>Number Two</Name>
       <Product>
          <Name>Number Three</Name>
       </Product>
   </Product>
</Product>
```

So basically, as soon as I've iterated through that node, my new xml shall not include in once again.

So I need to retree based on my xslt

what I have so far:

```
<Products>
                <xsl:for-each select="*:PIMXMLExport[fn:namespace-uri() eq '']/*:group[fn:namespace-uri() eq '']">
                    <Product>
                        <Name>
                            <xsl:for-each select="(./*:Name[fn:namespace-uri() eq '']/node())[fn:boolean(self::text())]">
                                <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </Name>
                        <xsl:for-each select="*:setgroup[fn:namespace-uri() eq '']/*:refgroup[fn:namespace-uri() eq '']">
                            <Product>
                                    <Name>
                                     <xsl:variable name="header_pos" select="@OIDRef"/>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="/PIMXMLExport/group[@asimoid = $header_pos]/Name"/>
                                    </Name>
                            </Product>
                        </xsl:for-each> 
                    </Product>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Products>
```

Comment: The refgroup rules seem odd - how do you know whether to put product 'c' as  a child of 'a' or 'b'?

Comment: Please post minimal but complete and well-formed snippets of the XML input and wanted output. Your `refgroup` elements are never closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those problems that becomes an awful lot easier if you use XSLT the way it was designed to be used: with xsl:apply-templates and template rules rather than nested xsl:for-each and conditionals.

The key aspects of the solution are:

(a) a template rule that processes `<group>` elements:

```
<xsl:template match="group">
<Product>
  <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</Product>
</xsl:template>
```

(b) a key to find groups by ID

```
<xsl:key name="gpKey" match="group" use="id"/>
```

(c) a template rule that matches refgroup elements:

```
<xsl:template match="refgroup">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('gpKey', @ID)"/>
</xsl:template>
```